# Specifiying invoation count from XML invocation

Tags: testng

I have an existing TestNG test case. I want to make a stress test by running the test case in parallel in a number of threads. One way to do this is to change the `@Test` annotation to be

```
@Test(invocationCount = 100, threadPoolSize=10)
```

but I do not want to edit the original (I want to leave it as a functional test). I would prefer to set the invocation count in my XML test suite definition.

As a work around, I created a new test with a high invocation count and in that test just call the old test. This solution works but feels like a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around, I created a new test with a high invocation count and in that test just call the old test. This solution works but feels like a hack.

This is not an ideal solution, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the `@Test` annotation at runtime with an [IAnnotationTransformer](http://testng.org/doclava/reference/org/testng/IAnnotationTransformer.html).

Comment: True, though it seems like overkill for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set invocationCount in XML file by using beanshell script like below:

```
<test name="TestName" >
    <method-selectors>
            <method-selector>
                <script language="beanshell">
                <![CDATA[
                testngMethod.setInvocationCount(2);
                return true;
                ]]>
                </script>
            </method-selector>
    </method-selectors>
        <classes>
            <class name="testNG.test" />
        </classes>
</test>
```

Change count accordingly, above xml configuration will execute test case twice.